# mount an [IPADDRESS]/dir on 12.04 in terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, mount

This is probably a super simple question, but googles failing me.

In windows, I can map a network drive, and point it to "\10.10.0.28\sample_folder" and it works just fine. On my Ubuntu machine, I have no idea how to perform this task.

Ideally I would like to mount it for future usage, as its going to be a pretty integral part of my workflow for a long time to come.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for or not.

If you open Nautilus (the default file manager in Ubuntu) and go to `Go -> Network`.

[image]

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.  Then you can enter a network address.

[image]

Please correct me if this doesn't help.

Comment: Ah yes, i do know how to do this in the gui, but im specifically looking for terminal commands to use, i appreciate the effort displayed in the answer though!